# unchecked warnings - during compilation when used Safe Args to pass data

Tags: android, bundle, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I use Navigation Component's Safe Args to pass data between destination

**build.gradle**
`apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"`

**MyType.kt**

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
class MyType(
        val type: String,
        val name: String
) : Parcelable
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<action android:id="@+id/startMyFragment"
    app:destination="@+id/myFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="myArg"
        app:argType="com.myapp.MyType"
        app:nullable="false" />
</action>
```

Above navigation graph creates lot of warnings during compilation. Could someone suggest how to avoid those warnings

```
 where K,V are type-variables:
     K extends Object declared in class HashMap
     V extends Object declared in class HashMap
 /builds/my-app/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/myapp/MyType.java:19: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type HashMap
       this.arguments.put("myArg", myArg);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add the code snippet where you are setting these args?

Comment: Please check the code snippet above (nav_graph.xml)

Comment: I mean where are you passing these args i.e : `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate`

Comment: val directions = MyDirection.actionStartMyFragment(label,detailArgs)
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(directions)

Comment: Where're you calling the `setArgs(MyType())` ?

Comment: No need to do setArgs(MyType()).  I think, android will take care of setArgs internally

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Comment: Using the same resource you provided, You need to pass the data.

Comment: could you provide an example please? github or code snipppet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Navgraph, the argument ist not within the action, here each Fragment sends the Args to the other:

additionally to the safeargs library, ich have also these:

```
def nav_version = '2.3.0'
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

navgraph:

```
     <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentX"
            android:name="package.FragmentX"
            android:label="Fragment 1">

        <argument
                android:name="userinput"
                app:argType="package.dataclasses.UserParcel"
                app:nullable="true"
                android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragmentX_to_fragmentY"
                app:destination="@id/fragmentY"
               />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragmentY"
                android:name="package.FragmentY"
                android:label="Fragment 2"
              >
          
            <argument
                    android:name="useripnut"
                    app:argType="package.dataclasses.UserParcel"
                app:nullable="true"
                android:defaultValue="@null" />
      
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_fragmentY_to_fragmentX"
                app:destination="@id/fragmentX"  />
        
    </fragment>
```

How to Get Data in Fragment X:

```
val args = FragmentXArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
```

How to Pass Data to Fragment Y:

```
 val navController = activity?.findNavController(R.id.navHost)
                            navController?.navigate(FragmentXDirections.actionFragmentXToFragmentY(userParcel))
```